# How to use custom precision in MPI_reduce?

Tags: fortran, mpi

I want to use custom precision in MPI_reduce. I create my own precision by MPI_TYPE_CREATE_F90_Real, but it seems that MPI_reduce cannot recognize the custom precision.

Here is my fortran code. Compile with "f2py -c --f90exec=mpif90 --fcompiler=gfortran --f90flags="-fopenmp" -lgomp test.f90 -m testsum"

```
Module testsum
implicit none
Contains

subroutine Test(comm, vec, s)
use mpi
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: comm
integer :: rank, ntask, ierr, stat
Integer, Parameter :: dp = Selected_Real_Kind(15,307)
integer :: I, N
integer, allocatable :: workload(:)
real (kind=dp), intent(in) :: vec(:)
Real (kind=dp), intent(out) :: s
real (kind=dp) :: si
integer :: istart, iend, mpi_dp
call MPI_Comm_size(comm, ntask, ierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(comm, rank, ierr)
Call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_F90_Real(15, 307, mpi_dp, ierr)
N = size(vec)
Allocate(workload(ntask))
workload = N / ntask
workload(1:mod(N,ntask)) = workload(1:mod(N,ntask)) + 1
istart = sum(workload(1:rank))
iend = istart + workload(rank+1)
si = 0.0_dp
s = 0.0_dp
Do I = istart+1, iend
    si = si + vec(I)
End Do
Call MPI_reduce(si,s,1,MPI_dp,MPI_Sum,0,comm,ierr)
Call MPI_Bcast(s,1,MPI_dp,0,comm,ierr)
Print *, s
end subroutine

End Module
```

run in Python

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import testsum
fcomm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.py2f()
vec = np.ones(80)
s = testsum.testsum.test(fcomm, vec)
print(s)
```

And I get s as 0.0. However, if I replace MPI_dp with MPI_DOUBLE, I can get the right answer. How to fix this issue? Also, I try MPI_Send and MPI_Recv, they can work for this custom precision.

Comment: If send/receive work but reduce not, it may be a bug in your MPI.

Comment: Could be anything. We need a complete code showing the issue to say much more.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout I guess MPI_SUM can only work for certain datatype.

Comment: @IanBush I upload my complete code.

Comment: This is not a complete code. We need a complete program we can compile and test, not just a subroutine.

Comment: @IanBush upload my complete code.

Comment: Did you do the obvious and check the error code returned by the call to `mpi_type_create_f90_real`?

Comment: 1. It works for my compiler. 2. This is bad MPI programming: each process has a copy of the whole array, but fills in only a couple of elements. I suspect that you're treating MPI as if it's a shared memory system. It's not. You should give each process an array of size `workload` and fill in ony the elements for that process.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark it returns 0